# Postgres pgpool increase num_init_children

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I am trying to tune postgre to allow many concurrent queries from clients as i am checking how many parallel connections with there queries it can handle.
 I read [A good PgPool II configurataion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362032/a-good-pgpool-ii-configurataion)
  , but what really can help to handle many concurrent connections with queries is to set up (**num_init_children = 1000** , for example 1000 parallel queries )

If i set up num_init_children = 2000 server fails to start.
 
My pgpool config is:

```
num_init_children = 1000                        
max_pool = 4     
child_life_time = 120
child_max_connections = 100
connection_life_time = 120
client_idle_limit = 10
```

How can i increase **num_init_children** or tune some parameters to allow 2, 5 or 10k parallel queries at the same time, cause it's really frustrating that postgre stucks with more that 1000 queries?

Comment: Don't do that. PostgreSQL won't perform well with more than a few hundred parallel queries. Queue them up instead, that's why you use a connection pooler.

Comment: instead postgre does not queue queries on client and i get error.
Client 430 aborted in state 1. Probably the backend died while processing.

Comment: You need to configure PgPool so *it* queues queries, and you don't exceed the server's `max_connections`.

Answer (score 2):

You're increasing `num_init_children`, but there's no sign you've set the PostgreSQL server backend's `max_connections` high enough to allow that number of connections from PgPool.

Please see [the PgPool-II documentation](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Documentation) to learn more about configuring PgPool-II. You might find [this article](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Relationship_between_max_pool,_num_init_children,_and_max_connections) useful.

You *really don't want* thousands of parallel queries to the backend database. What you need is for PgPool to queue them up and send them a few hundred at a time to PostgreSQL. Otherwise you'll tend to see terrible performance; see [number of database connections](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections) in the Pg wiki. So you need to limit the number of back-end connections PgPool-II creates, while allowing lots of front-end connections. That means you want a *low* `num_init_children`. Personally I'd use something like:

```
num_init_children = 100                        
max_pool = 1
```

because, per the documentation:

> If more than num_init_children clients try to connect to pgpool-II, they are blocked (not rejected) until a connection to any pgpool-II process is closed.

This is what you want for good performance.

That said, I use PgBouncer for this. I find it much simpler to work with, and it tends to perform very well. It also offers transaction-pooling mode, which can be really useful when you have applications that don't close connections, instead leaving them idle for ages. If you're not using PgPool's cluster features I strongly recommend just using PgBouncer, it's way simpler.